# CSS3 Transform only plays first item

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to get my div to rotate 360deg every time I click it, using CSS3 transform rotate. However, I'm also using the CSS3 transform translate to vertically align my div.

On the first click, it applies all the required CSS but doesn't actually rotate, however will rotate all clicks after that. It stays vertically aligned the whole time.

Unsure how to solve this and any help is appreciated :)

My css:

```
    #my-div {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;

        /*to vertically align*/
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

My javascript

```
var angle = 360
        $('#my-div').click(function() {
            $(this).css({
                '-webkit-transform' : 'translateY(-50%) rotate('+angle+'deg) ',
                'transform' : 'translateY(-50%) rotate('+angle+'deg)'
            })
            angle += 360
        });
```

Comment: You need to also use a `transition` so that you can see the transform :) Otherwise it's instant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the transition works ***properly*** only when the 2 ends are explicitly set, here intially the `rotate` transform is not set explicitly, after the first click, it's explicitly set to `rotate(360deg)` and hence the next clicks work. To solve this, you just need to apply `rotate(0deg)` for your div initially via the CSS code:

```
#my-div {
   /*...*/
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
}
```

Note that I emphasized on the *properly* word, in fact if you set the initial angle to some angle equal or smaller than `180deg`, you'll see it transitions OK. I doubt that if you don't set the initial rotate transform explicitly, the behavior is determined by the browser, that is `360deg` won't make any transition, otherwise the rotating transition may be clockwise (if the `angle % 360` is less than or equal to `180deg`) and counter-clockwise if the `angle % 360` is greater than `180deg` (note about the modulo operation between `angle` and `360`).

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/uaw55/)